# Angular FormControl XNOR validator for two fields based on having value or being empty

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

I have two fields on a form group of 4. 2 of them are pure required so that's simple. The other two must either be both empty or both have a value - basically an XNOR state.

```
s1_male     s1_female      s1_male_valid     s1_female_valid
empty       empty          true              true
value       empty          false             false
empty       value          false             false
value       value          true              true
```

The code below works however it doesn't update the UI properly. For instance if I enter a value in s1_male then it flags as invalid but s1_female doesn't. If I then enter a value in s1_female that remains valid but s1_male is still marked as invalid. I then have to go back to s1_male and either delete and re-enter the value or change it and then change it back to what I want.

I've tried calling `updateValueAndValidity()` on both fields during the below function but this just causes an endless loop that Chrome eventually kills.

```
formGroup.addControl('rx_male', new FormControl('', Validators.required));
formGroup.addControl('rx_female', new FormControl('', Validators.required));
formGroup.addControl('s1_male', new FormControl('', this.scaleOptionValidator(formGroup)));
formGroup.addControl('s1_female', new FormControl('', this.scaleOptionValidator(formGroup)));

// these line cause endless loop
formGroup.controls.s1_male.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  formGroup.controls.s1_female.updateValueAndValidity();
});
formGroup.controls.s1_female.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  formGroup.controls.s1_male.updateValueAndValidity();
});

...

private scaleOptionValidator(formGroup: FormGroup): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      let isValid = false;
      const female = formGroup.controls.s1_female;
      const male = formGroup.controls.s1_male;
      if (male && female) {

        if ((male.value && female.value) || (!male.value && !female.value)) {
          isValid = true;
        }

        return isValid ? null : { scalseNotValid: true };
      }
      return null;
    };
  }
```

Suggestions would be great

UPDATE:
So it looks like the formgroup approach is working however I am using Ionic here as well asn frustratingly even though the ng-invalid class is being applied the ion-valid class is over riding the UI styling until select and then deselect the input field.

Comment: Suggestion: Create an inner `FormGroup` for "s1" fields and apply your validator to that group. This way you won't need the `scaleOptionValidator` function.

Comment: Can you try distinctUntilChanged() in the pipeline just before subscribe() for valuechanges?

Comment: @Shofol that stops the endless loop but still see the same ui behaviour, it only changes the validation state for the field being edited and not the other one, even though I can see that `updateValueAndValidity()` is being called

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did when I needed to validate the 2 password fields in my sign up form.

```
shouldMatch(group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null {
    const password = group.get("password")
    const retypedPassword = group.get("retypedPassword")

    if (password !== null && retypedPassword !== null) {
        return password.value === retypedPassword.value ? null : { mismatch: true }
    } else {
        throw new Error("The form group is invalid. The group does not have a 'password' and/or a 'retypedPassword' control.")
    }
}
```

You can use a similar approach. In my sign up `FormGroup` I added an inner `FormGroup` for the passwords. Then I added a validator to that group. I used the inner group's validity status for showing error messages.

---

You can add a getter to reduce the amount of code that gets written in the template.

```
get passwords(): FormGroup {
    return this.signupForm.get("passwords") as FormGroup
}
```

Comment: How do I then access the inner formgroup in my form, I'm already referencing a formgroup in there since this is part of an array of form groups. i can't seem to add it correctly in a way that the UI can bind to it

Comment: You can use the `FormGroup#get` method to get the inner group.

Comment: I have updated my answer to address your 2nd question.